# How to play movie with .mov extension in browser

Tags: html, quicktime

I have tried the following HTML code and neither works for playing .mov files in Firefox or IE

```
<video controls="controls" src="video/video_1429118630.MOV">Your browser does not support the <code>video</code> element.</video>-->

<embed src="video/video_1429118630.MOV" 
       Pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/" 
       width="320" height="250" CONTROLLER="true" LOOP="false" 
       AUTOPLAY="false">
</embed>
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong, the video couldn't play because the MIME type being sent is not supported. Try serving  the video from a web server such us Apache and the MIME type will be automatically set for you.
Here is a [link](http://help.encoding.com/knowledge-base/article/correct-mime-types-for-serving-video-files/) of MIME types of some common video file extension

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Is it possible to set the mime type? I thought that it could be done with the video tag?